# SolrJ get total facets without retrieve all facets

Tags: solr, solrj, facet

This code returns the first 10 facet items (out of about 200) for fieldx:

```
    query.setQuery("*:*");
    query.setFacet(true);
    query.addFacetField("fieldx");
    query.setFacetLimit(10);
    QueryResponse resp = solr.query(query);
    System.out.println("tot="+resp.getResults().getNumFound());
```

I need to get the total number of facets items (200 in this case) so that I can do pagination of the facet set.  `resp.getResults().getNumFound()` returns the total number of documents (31,000,000), not the total # of facet items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the facetField from the response and then ask for the count. For instance:

```
FacetField fieldxFacets = solrResponse.getFacetField("fieldx");
int countFacets = fieldxFacets.getValueCount();
```

looking at the [FacetField code in GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/4.4.0/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/FacetField.java#FacetField.getValueCount%28%29) that's what you need.

In order to return the total count of facets,  you could set the limit to -1 (unlimited)  however you should put a lower limit as I don't see a scenario where a user does deep pagination on facets.

Comment: this does not work because `fieldxFacets.getValueCount()` return the facet number returned (10 in this case), not the total facets.

Comment: how do you know that you have 200 facets? If that method returns just 10, but you're sure at 100% that they are 200 then there's a possibility that you're setting the limit. Try setting the limit using facet.limit=-1 (unlimited)

Comment: Sorry, I can see in your code that you're setting facets limit 10, that's your problem. Set it to -1 if you'd like to get all the facets or an upper limit if you like to display less

Comment: That's the issue here. I need to know the total facets without retrieval all facets. I am making a facet pagination. In this case, the total facets are 200. The next one can be 20,000. If I know the total facets, then I can make a paging at 20 docs a time (using facet.offset)

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, you can set the limit to -1 and then use get value count. That would solve your issue,  however if you should put a lower limit as I don't see a scenario where a user does deep pagination on facets.